# xml use for content and markup

Tags: xml

I am reading about xml at plural sight training. Here author is mentioned as below.

> One of the big concepts in XML is content and markup.Content is
>   something an author writes and an editor marks up that contentto
>   classify what the pieces of text in it are.For example this is a
>   title, this is a quote, this is a chapter.Then the marked up content
>   is processed to produce a printed document.Maybe it goes and drives a
>   typesetter that sets up printing presses.This fits nicely into the way
>   that programs typically work with data because it correspondsto data
>   and metadata and it's one of the reasons why XML is so useful for
>   representing data.

My question is what does author mean by "This fits nicely into the way that programs typically work with data because it correspondsto data and metadata" ? How xml corresponding to data and meta data? Request to clarify with simple example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right what the author means is that if we have a markup that looks like this:

```
<book author="George R.R Martin" title="A Game of Thrones" type="pocket" 
ISBN="978-0-553-57340-4">
    <chapter title="Prologue">
        <page number="1">"We should start back"...</page>
    </chapter>
    <chapter title="Bran">
        <page number="15">The morning had...</page>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

This is easily passed on between programs from place to place and it keeps the same structure, I.E the data will be kept intact.

Compare this to a CSV:

```
George R.R Martin, pocket, 978-0-553-57340-4, Prologue, "We should start back"...
```

What's data and metadata here? How do we know that the correct value is parsed when we're supposed to print our pocket?
We don't know, so we have to try and hope that we've given the correct input to the printer.
I might have gotten the author all wrong since he uses the word data and not information, which is the more correct word according to me when it comes to XML (when you put data into a XML format it should become structured data and understandable, according to me).

To sum up what I think the author means:

Corresponding to data and metadata is having a structured and well formed format to follow in the whole production line, in his example this would be from the author to the reader, there's no question what's a page and what's a title f.ex.
Examples of common formats used in programming would be: XHTML, documents, RSS and so on.
These are formats used by different programs and on different OS, but it doesn't matter as long as we have the same Markup because we know that no matter who wants to access our data because it'll (hopefully) correspond to the format we said.